# Bing maps - Google maps difference in coordinates

Tags: android, google-maps, bing-maps, markers

I am building an Android map that uses Googles Maps, that is going to have the exact same markers(same longitude and latitude) as a desktop (.NET) app that uses Bing maps.

To my surprise the markers in the Android/Google Maps app are not placed in the exact same position as in the desktop/Bing Maps app. There is a certain misplacement that seems a bit "random".
As an example I entered a specific location in Google Maps and Bing Maps and you can check the misplacement
([here](http://www.bing.com/mapspreview?v=2&cp=51.517335~-0.104261&lvl=20&sty=r&q=51.5175125,-0.1042591&form=LMLTCC) and [here](https://www.google.com/maps/place/51%C2%B031'03.0%22N+0%C2%B006'15.3%22W/@51.5175735,-0.1043746,21z/data=!4m2!3m1!1s0x0:0x0) - the misplacement in the Android phone is much more intense.)
Is this a known issue? Is there any known workaround? How can I avoid manually changing the markers that exist in the desktop app, to port them in the Android app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a fairly common issue. The imagery in Google Maps tends to be less accurately positioned than the imagery in Bing Maps. In North America and Western Europe Bing Maps imagery has a position accuracy of +/- 1.5 meters according to tests done by the European Joint Research Commission. Google Maps on the other had has been found to have it's imagery out of place by as much as 1.5 miles in some areas.

Comment: Although I believe there is a small possibility being a bit biased  towards Bing maps (since you contributed in their development), thank you for your answer.

Comment: Actually I've been in technical sales and not on the engineering side of things. I've spent a lot of time looking into issues like this for customers.

Answer (score 3):

The Bing map link is looking at a lat/lon of :    51.5175125,-0.1042591

The Google map link is looking at a lat/lon of: 51.5175735,-0.1043746

There is a slight difference in the co-ordinates.

If you put in the exact same lat/lon, they come out the same.

[Bing](http://www.bing.com/mapspreview?v=2&cp=51.517611~-0.104318&lvl=20&sty=r&eo=0&q=51.5175735,-0.1043746&form=LMLTCC)

[Google](https://www.google.com/maps/place/51%C2%B031'03.3%22N+0%C2%B006'15.8%22W/@51.5175914,-0.1043867,20z/data=!4m2!3m1!1s0x0:0x0)

Comment: This is really weird, because I copy-pasted the coordinates :/

Comment: There is actually a very tiny difference if you zoom in, it seems less than 1m. Looking at it, Bing seems to round to 6 decimal digits where as Google uses 7 decimal digits. I think that could account for such a tiny difference, but they are basically the same.

Comment: 6 decimal places has an accuracy of +/- 30cm, which is the size of one pixel at zoom level 19, the closest zoom level.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid this is an error of Google respective Microsoft. Maps are calibrated and little discrepancies with randomness depending on the quality of calibration and distance from the calibration points are possible.

For example, here is no difference - compare [Bing](http://www.bing.com/mapspreview?v=2&where1=50.011813,%2014.476304&form=LMLTSN&cp=50.011694892520914~14.476371928185522&lvl=20&sty=h&encType=1) and [Google](https://www.google.com/maps/place/50%C2%B000'42.5%22N+14%C2%B028'34.7%22E/@50.0118773,14.4759144,21z/data=!4m2!3m1!1s0x0:0x0)

Answer (score 0):

I found that out comparing points in south america (both fit perfectly well) and in Western Europe (Bing Maps differs from Google AND from OSM).